# Should I Learn C# or Java?

Tags: c#, java, database, user-interface, programming-languages

I am  a second year Computer Engineering student and I need to study in-depth GUI with database programming.

I am not completely new to it as I have made some mini-projects in C#...and Java... But now need to master the subject.

My Question is in which language is well equipped and demanding(market prospective) Java or C#?

Obviously I cannot do both of them and I know that most of the coding in Java and C# are the same.... but as far as GUI and Database programming is concerned there are some differences...
Also some reference Text books will be of great help :-))

Comment: It's like asking if eggs are best boiled or scrambled. And, you can and SHOULD do more than programming language, don't restrict yourself to one. As of book recommendations I'm sure you'll find plenty of questions about that on the site using google.

Comment: I want to emphasize that I didn't vote for this close reason, I thought it should go to programmers.se.  But there's [already such a question over there](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/63860/should-i-take-the-java-or-c-at-university), you might want to read those answers.

Comment: @larsm I disagree that this question is not constructive. I asked the same question when I was a student, I started with Java and ended up switching to C# because I needed something that links up better with Windows. Instead of just saying its like eggs, I think there are some conciderations that can be mentioned. He's a student - what he is really asking is "What are the differences between C# and Java to take into account when choosing a platform for this or that application". That's a constructive question. Although I agree it might go down better at programmers.stackexchange

Comment: Thanks Harikawashi .....:-) and 
@larsm : I know as a programmer we should be clear in basics of several languages... But you didnt read my post clearly... I asked i need to MASTER the language so as to be in better competition!!! Besides I am known to some other programming languages.....:-P

Comment: @killerCoder: you'll probably learn more about Java and C# from learning a language that radically differs from (e.g. a functional language) and digging deeper into their APIs. True mastery comes from diversity.

Comment: people learn a Programming language out of love for programming and not seeing the "market prospective" of it. So go ahead and learn both. Or just start with any one. Anyway, none of them will make you the richest man on earth, but might end up making you the happiest man on earth.

Comment: You are in an educational institution.  Learn as much you can of exciting things - you can learn all the boring stuff on your own later.  To find out what is the most exciting stuff at your institution go talk to the older students!

Comment: @aps : Yes friend..... You are right... By the way, 
People, Please try to answer my first question na, It is about accessing the Video Resources from the Deploy file in a published Click Once Application.... I have been trying it from birth!!!!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on your target systems... I would say it is generally faster to develop in C# in Visual Studio than in Java. Also C# ties into Microsoft SQL Server very nicely. C# and .NET 4.0 offers you Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) for building GUI's, which I find to be superior to Windows Forms or Java GUI's, although I haven't worked with Java in a couple of years and last time I built a Java GUI it was with Swing.

There is a lot of support from Microsoft for C# and MS SQL Server, and you can do most things for free (as with Java). If you are targeting Windows systems, I would go with C#.

**EDIT:** Also, LINQ-to-SQL is awesome, very intuitive way to access the database and get objects to work with. So another plus to C# from me.

Answer (score 3):

By "demanding" I think you mean to say "in demand".

Best thing to do is to look at the classified ads, see which kinds of companies are asking for java and which kinds are asking for C#, and then decide which of the two to emphasize based on your career goals and personal preferences.